# Firestore query function result is void

Tags: javascript, typescript

Function **validateBusinessId** results in void variable **businessExists**. I am trying to assign different database paths depending on whether the business exists in the database or if the uploaded file is a master file. Function **validateBusiness** produces void result. Not sure how to fix it. Where did I go wrong?

```
async function validateBusinessId(businessId: string) {
    db.collection('business').doc(businessId).get()
    .then((docSnapshot) => {
        if (docSnapshot.exists) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    })
}

async function getDatabase(fileName: string, businessId: string) {
    const businessExists = await validateBusinessId(businessId)

    if ((fileName) && (fileName?.includes('masterFile'))) {
        console.log('A new Master database file has been detected.')
        return db.collection('products')
    } else if ((businessId) && (businessExists)) {
        // If the business exists, return business path
        console.log('A new database file has been detected for business: ' + businessId)
        return db.collection('business').doc(businessId).collection('products')
    } else {
        return null
    }
}
```

Help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found that I handled the promise of a query result incorrectly. Here's the code that worked for me.

```
async function validateBusinessId(businessId: string) {
    const databaseDocumentSnapshot = await db.collection('business').doc(businessId).get()

    if (databaseDocumentSnapshot.exists) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

async function getDatabase(fileName: string, businessId: string) {
    const businessExists = await validateBusinessId(businessId)

    if ((fileName) && (fileName?.includes('masterFile'))) {
        console.log('A new Master database file has been detected.')
        return db.collection('products')
    } else if ((businessId) && (businessExists)) {
        return db.collection('business').doc(businessId).collection('products')
    } else {
        console.log('No business with such ID exists: ' + businessId);
        return null
    }
}
```